Before/after code smells refactoring examples in Java
I do not know much about Java programming, and it has been a long time since my last connection to StackExchange, so I hope my question will not be too off-topic!
I am looking for educational/teaching examples of code smells and refactoring in Java. Ideally, I would like to gather a "bank" of code snippets containing code smells (god classes, long method and feature envy are of most interest for me) and, if possible, their "clean" version.
Basically, I am looking for something pretty much similar to that quite old post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484686/refactoring-code-samples-before-and-after?noredirect=1&lq=1.
I tried to look out for code samples across scientific IT literature in Google scholar but was unsuccessful in doing so.
Which courses/tutorials/books would you recommand to access realistic/real-life Java samples containing code smells?
Many thanks for your help! Best regards

Code smells seem a topic for Software Engineering@SE.
